# Renaming only csv files in a directory using Shell

Tags: bash, sh

I'm replacing some contents in the files that have extension .csv in a directory . Is there a way to rename multiple files differently and using sed command.

For example The directory has two file with the following name

1. `data_20050523-20170409.csv`
2. `data_20050523-20170409FileHeader.csv`

I want to use sed and rename both files as different name for example

1. `new_data.csv`             or `data1.csv`
2. `new_data_header.csv`      or `data2.csv`

Is it possible to do so in Shell Script ?

```
DIR=/Users/test/Desktop/NPPES/

cd $DIR

sed 's/","/|/g;s/"/''/g' *.csv
echo Replace completed

#cd $DIR

#rm $FILE
#rm *.pdf
#chmod 777 *.csv
#echo file removed
echo Script completed
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
# Iterate over all csv files in folder
for csv in *.csv; do
    # Generate new name with sed
    new=`echo "$csv" | sed 's/something/something_else/'`
    # Rename csv if new name different
    [ "$new" = "$csv" ] || mv "$csv" "$new"
done
```

But there is also a `rename` utility, which can do this in one go, using a Perl expression:

```
rename 's/something/something_else/' *.csv
```

The problem is that there are 2 `rename` tools that work completely differently, the one from the `util-linux` Deb package is not the Perl based one.

Comment: Need double quotes around variables to prevent word splitting and globbing.

Comment: Yes sir! But I assume the best of the user, I'm sure he doesn't use whitespace and other evil characters in filenames. :)

Comment: That's a terrible assumption to make.

Comment: If the files were *.xlsx, I'm sure they would look like this: `TPS Report (modified by Steve)_version2.revised (approved).xlsx`